# How to avoid "Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to "false""

Tags: java, if-statement, sonarqube

Hello iam analyzing my code using sonarqube and am running into a bug for the following method

```
    final Boolean active = this.fromApiJsonHelper.extractBooleanNamed(GroupingTypesApiConstants.activeParamName, element);
        if (active != null) {
            if (active.booleanValue()) {
                final LocalDate joinedDate = this.fromApiJsonHelper.extractLocalDateNamed(
                        GroupingTypesApiConstants.activationDateParamName, element);
                baseDataValidator.reset().parameter(GroupingTypesApiConstants.activationDateParamName).value(joinedDate).notNull();
            } else {
                // TODO - KW - not using config for now - just supporting move
                // to pending or active out of box.
                final boolean isPendingApprovalEnabled = true;
                if (!isPendingApprovalEnabled) {
                    baseDataValidator.reset().parameter(GroupingTypesApiConstants.activeParamName)
                            .failWithCode(".pending.status.not.allowed");
                }
            }
        } else {
            baseDataValidator.reset().parameter(ClientApiConstants.activeParamName).value(active).trueOrFalseRequired(false);
        }
```

sonarqube saying that "Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to "false" , in statement "if (!isPendingApprovalEnabled)"

Comment: That code appears to be there as a placeholder. You can ignore the warning since it's not final code.

Comment: so i change the rule? and accept it ?

Comment: Why do you put code in your code-base that is never called?

Comment: I don't know the specific SonarCube rule, but you can try making the flag a `private static final boolean` field. I've used that for conditional compilation several times. Maybe SonarCube will accept that without warning.

Answer (score 0):

`isPendingApprovalEnabled` will never be false since it is initialized with `true` in the line before. As long as the line before is implemented in this way, the if statement is dead code.

You can either remove that code (and reintroduce it when you support a configuration) or replace the variable with a method.

```
  /* ... */
  if (!isPendingApprovalEnabled()) {
  /* ... */
}

private boolean isPendingApprovalEnabled() {
  // TODO - KW - not using config for now
  return true;
}
```